# Wait till tomcat startup is over

Tags: java, tomcat

I am executing startup.bat programatically to start a tomcat server.

```
ProcessBuilder processUnzip = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "C:\\apache-tomcat-6.0.37\\startup.bat");
```

I need to wait till the complete startup.bat process is over. But the program ends immediately after the startup.bat is started.

Is there a way to wait till startup process is over

**Update:**

My requirement is to deploy a WAR file in a tomcat instance. I cannot use hot deployment or dynamic deployment. I have to do a static deployment. Basically the task is to automate the manual process of build deployment in tomcat.

Comment: why don't you just copy the app to tomcat deployments folder before you start tomcat and let tomcat handle the deployment? can you clarify what you mean by "static deployment"?

Comment: I want to automate the process that you have explained

Comment: added it [as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19158653/365237)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate the process, you should copy the app to be deployed into tomcat deployments folder before you start the server up. If you copy any .war package to TOMCAT/webapps folder, it will get deployed by Tomcat when it starts up.

So what you need to do is to just copy the file. [here](http://www.journaldev.com/861/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java) are four different examples on how to do that in Java. Either that, or you can just exec a copy command.

Possibly easiest and least error prone is to do it using Files, in java 7:

```
Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
```

and after that is finished, then exec start command.

---

Update: with shutdown, you have the wait issue. You can wait doing something like this in a batch file:

```
CALL shutdown.bat
:LOOP
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Tomcat" | find /C /I ".exe" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  GOTO :EOF
) ELSE (
  ECHO Tomcat is still running
  SLEEP 1
  GOTO LOOP
)
```

This code assumes a Tomcat window with name 'Tomcat'. If you run Tomcat as a service, for example, that assumption is not true. For service however there are more reliable means using sc query:

```
SC stop "tomcat"
:LOOP
SC query "tomcat" | FIND "STATE" | FIND "RUNNING" > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  GOTO :EOF
) ELSE (
  ECHO Tomcat is still running
  SLEEP 1
  GOTO LOOP
)
```

Here assuming service name "tomcat".

Update2: forgot we're talking about java here - with the bat above, you can use java .waitFor(), or you can program the same logic in a java file as well.

Comment: It will not work for redeploy case. I need to make sure that tomcat is stopped before starting it again

Comment: @user2560360 for stopping the server you can use waitFor() that's been explained here in other answers.

Comment: Again the waitFor does not really wait till tomcat is stopped. Its just gets over after executing the command

Comment: Thanks @eis Shutdown can be achieved by the above. But my main concern is the startup process. I want to block every activity till startup is completed.

Comment: Like I already explained that you should not do that, but instead do the actions when server is not up. If you insist on having it, then you need to either do some log polling or check using wget if the application gives a response. You could put a some kind of heartbeat.jsp into your application and wget to the url until you get a response.

Answer (score 3):

You are facing this problem because `startup.bat` opens up a new window with Tomcat console and returns immediately.

Even if you use `catalina.bat` instead of `startup.bat`, that would still not work as that process would terminate only when Tomcat stops.

Technically, You would never know whether the tomcat is started on or until the logs tell you so. So the approach you are taking might not work.

The only crude solution I can think of is (*with the same code you have*), once you start the Tomcat, keep checking the console log file, at intervals, for specific string (like `Server started` etc) which indicate that the server has started.

BTW, if you could tell us your specific use case (why are you doing this ?), community here might come up with better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Runtime` to create a process and then wait for the process to finish.

You do that by doing the following.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start file.bat");
int exit_value = process.waitFor();
```

Where in your case the `file.bat` is the file you want to execute.

Comment: It does not wait till tomcat file.bat is completed. Process gets over once the file is invoked.

Comment: I thing, that the problem is, that the execution of process finishes successfully, but it takes some time until the server is in the state to be able to process requests.

Comment: even waiting for file completion will not do, it won't tell when the server is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the start command to run the batch file in the foreground - then, waitFor() will wait for the batch file completion:

> Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + path +
>   "\RunFromCode.bat");

If RunFromCode.bat executes the EXIT command, the command window is automatically closed. Otherwise, the command window remains open until you explicitly exit it with EXIT - the java process is waiting until the window is closed in either case.

Comment: waiting for file completion will not do, it won't tell when the server is ready.